# Find the maximum sum out of two sorted arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

There are two sorted arrays `A` and `B` of equal length where `A` is sorted in ascending order and array `B` is sorted in descending order.

```
A = {1, 3, 7, 7, 7, 7}
B = {7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4}
```

My task is to find two elements, one from `A` and other from `B`, so that their sum is maximum.

There is a constraint that I can choose any element from `A` but I have to choose the element from `B` in such an order that the index of the element of array `B` should be greater than that of the chosen element of `A`.

In this case, the maximum sum that can be chosen is `12`. I have done it in `O(n)` by simply iterating from left to right.

I want to know whether there exists any better and more efficient way to find the sum of those two elements.

Comment: Is it possible to find the answer without looking at all the elements of at least one array ?

Comment: @Bathsheba Please remark that the best match in B is always the element at the same index as the one you chose in A.

Comment: @fjardon, the *next* (incremented) index.

Comment: The last of B will be small.

Comment: @juanchopanza: because this would be the minimum ;-) and we search for the maximum

Comment: @Bathsheba B is sorted in descending order, you have to choose an index greater than the one for A, so the next index points to the gretatest allowed value in B for the index you chose in A.

Comment: @ fjardon: right, so you iterate over all indices, sum um A and B from the same index and save the index with the greates sum. easy task and O(n).

Comment: In c# it would be: A.Zip(B.Skip(1)).Select((a,b)=>a+b).Max()

Answer (score 5):

We know that the best sum is the largest value among the sequence `C` obtained by adding `A` and `B` pairwise.

`A` and `B` are monotonic, but `C` can be arbitrary, so there is no shortcut, you need to compute the whole of `C`, and `O(N)` is optimal.

Comment: Please prove that C is arbitrary

Comment: Changed one of your words. Roll back if you don't like it. @fjardon: that's a good point.

Comment: Let `A=0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3` and `B=4,3,3,2,2,1,1,0`. Then `C=4,3,4,3,4,3,4,3`, which has `N/2` local maxima.

Comment: @fjardon: yep, false friend to French.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Good, I'm pleased and upvoted your answer :) That was the tricky part indeed.

Comment: Other form of the argument: let `A[i]=2i` and `B[i]=-2i`; you can modify some `A[k]=2k+1`, and that moves the maximum anywhere you like.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes I thought about your later example, but it doesn't prove the point. Because there is a single maximum/minimum and you can still use binary search to find that maximum and then binary search on the two subranges. The fact you can create an arbitrary sequence proves that if an algorithm doesn't look at **all** values, one could craft a second sequence with a higher value just where the algorithm won't look at. And thus, this algorithm isn't correct

Comment: @fjardon: no, the use of binary search would be motivated by the fact that there is a single maximum. But you don't know that in advance. For a sequence with no special property, there is no better way than exhaustive search.

Comment: @YvesDaoust exactly, I wasn't clear. I spoke about your latest example. Your example of an arbitrary sequence is indeed the cornerstone of the proof one cannot devise a better algorithm than `O(n)`.

Comment: @fjardon: yep, with real numbers or integers sufficiently spaced, you can create an example such that C is in any order, ie. completely unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

As Yves Daoust points out, in principle, O(n) is optimal, but you can do some simple tricks, to save time in practice.

You can make usage of the maximum value of A.

```
const int maxA = A[sizeA-1];
```

In your loop, you can check the following two conditions to savely abort your loop searching for the maximum ( i is your loop variable).

```
// since B will be smaller the next time and A is at its max, no need to go further
if ( A[i] >= maxA ) break; 

// if there is no chance left, to find a greater sum, since even maxA with the biggest
// B we are about to see is not big enough, break.
if ( maxA + B[i] <= currentMax ) break;
```

Comment: It doesn't necessary save time as you do 2 more checks by element (and in work case, it will take more time).

Comment: Might be, and I think the first check is not as likely to succeed as the second one.

Comment: @Jarod42: you are right. Whatever the values in the array, the loop must run at least up to the maximum, which is halfway on average; and in many cases, it will continue, possibly to the end. As the test for the maximum is a very simple operation, the combined "time saving" tricks represent a superior cost.